# Extract ellipse shape food plate from image through Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

[Food Plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1QD4.jpg)

The idea is to extract the plate which is in the shape of an ellipse.
I tried the `HoughCircles` method from OpenCV but it only works for perfect circles.
I also tried the `hough_ellipse` method from `skimage` but it is taking too long or I implemented it the wrong way.
Is it possible to detect ellipse shape using the OpenCV module?

What other solutions exist?

Food Plate:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main key for extracting the plate is using [cv2.adaptiveThreshold](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=adaptivethreshold), but there are few more stages:

- Convert to Grayscale and apply adaptive threshold with relatively large Gaussian.
- Find connected components (clusters).
  Find largest cluster, and create new image with only the largest cluster.
- Use "open" morphological operation for removing some artifacts.
- Fill the plate with white pixels (using floodFill).
- Find contours, and get the contour with maximum area.
- Draw contour with maximum size to create a mask.
  Apply the mask on the original image.

Finding the ellipse by shape, is much less robust...

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils

img = cv2.imread('food_plate.jpg')

# Convert to Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply adaptive threshold with gaussian size 51x51
thresh_gray = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, adaptiveMethod=cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, thresholdType=cv2.THRESH_BINARY, blockSize=51, C=0)

#cv2.imwrite('thresh_gray.png', thresh_gray)

# Find connected components (clusters)
nlabel,labels,stats,centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh_gray, connectivity=8)

# Find second largest cluster (the cluster is the background):
max_size = np.max(stats[1:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA])
max_size_idx = np.where(stats[:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] == max_size)[0][0]

mask = np.zeros_like(thresh_gray)

# Draw the cluster on mask
mask[labels == max_size_idx] = 255

# Use "open" morphological operation for removing some artifacts
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5)))

#cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)

# Fill the plate with white pixels
cv2.floodFill(mask, None, tuple(centroids[max_size_idx].astype(int)), newVal=255, loDiff=1, upDiff=1)

#cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)

# Find contours, and get the contour with maximum area
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Draw contours with maximum size on new mask
mask2 = np.zeros_like(mask)
cv2.drawContours(mask2, [c], -1, 255, -1)

#cv2.imwrite('mask2.png', mask2)

img[(mask2==0)] = 0

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('img.jpg', img)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation + code. I'm quite new to OpenCV so appreciate the effort. Btw the code is specific to this scenario. The idea is to extract the plate shape in all such images(food photography) i.e. to basically find the ellipse/circle in the image.

Comment: I think first stage of the finding the ellipse shape is separating the foreground from the background (using `adaptiveThreshold` for example). Don't expect to get generic solutions for difficult problems in Stack Overflow. You didn't show any effort solving the problem yourself (you didn't post your code) and in most cases such questions are never answered.